# Upload a pdf file with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swagger

I got the following function which got created from swagger code gen:

```
 open class func uploadFile(firstname: String, lastname: String, timestamp: Date, file: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ data: ApiResponse?,_ error: Error?) -> Void)) {
```

In the app you can make an image with the camera and the image got converted to a pdf file:

```
let document = PDFDocument()
let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: unwrapImage)
document.insert(pdfPage!,at: 0)
```

So now I want to upload this document. But `document.documentURL` is always nil. Although I can display the pdf docuemnt on the display. Am I supposed to save the pdf document to a temp directory to use the function with the url parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFDocument's property `documentURL` is get only. If you do not use the url initializer it will always return nil. What you need is to get your PDFDocument `dataRepresentation` and `write` the pdf data to a url at a temporary or permanent location. Then you can upload its URL.

```
let document = PDFDocument()
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName.jpg")!
if let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image) {
    document.insert(pdfPage,at: 0)
    do {
        print(FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.path)
        let fileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("pdfName.pdf")
        try document.dataRepresentation()?.write(to: fileURL)
        // upload your fileURL or copy to a permanent location
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```